# Dagger 2 - IncompatiblyScopedBindings

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I’m trying to create an basic architecture with Dagger 2 for my study project but I have encountered several problems with it…

The current error daggers tell me

`FeedMeApplicationComponent.java:7: error: [Dagger/IncompatiblyScopedBindings] .FeedMeApplicationComponent (unscoped) may not reference scoped bindings:`

I only have this problem when I add the `ActivityMainModule` as a module of the application

and ActivityMainModule contains a sub component only related to the MainActivity.

I don’t understand why I cannot add this module of sub component to the Application Graph :confusing

Those are my Dagger classes…

```
class FeedMeApplication : DaggerApplication() {

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerFeedMeApplicationComponent.factory().create(this)
    }
}
```

```
@Component(modules = [AndroidInjectionModule::class, NetworkModule::class, NutritionModule::class, ActivityMainModule::class])
interface FeedMeApplicationComponent : AndroidInjector<FeedMeApplication> {

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance context: Context): FeedMeApplicationComponent
    }

    override fun inject(instance: FeedMeApplication?)
}
```

```
@Module
object NetworkModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    fun provideNutritionService(retrofit: Retrofit): NutritionService {
        return retrofit.create(NutritionService::class.java)
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    fun provideRetrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl("https://api.edamam.com/api")
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    fun provideOkHttp(): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient()
            .newBuilder()
            .addInterceptor(ApiInterceptor())
            .build()
    }

    private class ApiInterceptor : Interceptor {
        override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
            val request = chain.request().newBuilder()
            request
                .addHeader("api_id", “abc")
                .addHeader("app_key", “123")
            return chain.proceed(request.build())
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Module
object NutritionModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    fun provideNutritionRepository(nutritionService: NutritionService): NutritionRepository {
        return NutritionRepository(nutritionService)
    }
}
```

```
@Module(subcomponents = [MainActivityComponent::class], includes = [MainModule::class])
abstract class ActivityMainModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ClassKey(MainActivity::class)
    abstract fun bindAndroidInjector(factory: MainActivityComponent.Factory): AndroidInjector.Factory<*>
}

@Module
object MainModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    fun provideMainViewModelFactory(nutritionRepository: NutritionRepository): MainViewModel.Factory {
        return MainViewModel.Factory(nutritionRepository)
    }

    @Provides
    @JvmStatic
    fun provideMainViewModel(
        viewModelFactory: MainViewModel.Factory,
        fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity
    ): MainViewModel {
        return ViewModelProviders.of(fragmentActivity, viewModelFactory)
            .get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    }
}
```

```
@ActivityScope
@Subcomponent
interface MainActivityComponent : AndroidInjector<MainActivity> {

    @Subcomponent.Factory
    interface Factory : AndroidInjector.Factory<MainActivity> {}
}
```

```
class MainActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var mainViewModel: MainViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mainViewModel.liveDataFoodAnalysis.observe(this, Observer { food ->
            Log.d("Food answer", food.uri)
        })
        mainViewModel.getFoodAnalysisResponse("egg")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to `annotate` `FeedMeApplicationComponent` with `@Singleton`. because both `NetworkModule` and `NutritionModule` define `@Provides` functions scoped with `@Singleton`, any component that uses these modules must also specify its own scope as `@Singleton`.

From [Dagger docs](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/): -

> Since Dagger 2 associates scoped instances in the graph with instances
>   of component implementations, the components themselves need to
>   declare which scope they intend to represent. For example, it wouldn’t
>   make any sense to have a @Singleton binding and a @RequestScoped
>   binding in the same component because those scopes have different
>   lifecycles and thus must live in components with different lifecycles.
>   To declare that a component is associated with a given scope, simply
>   apply the scope annotation to the component interface.